# I get a bug when I run a test from The Odin Projects JS lesson

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs

I'm trying to run a test from The Odin Project lesson. When I ran it, it stopped running at the 'RUN' stage.[test stuck at run from The Odin Project, Foundation JS 05_sumAll exercise.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl03Z.png)

I'm not sure why it's stuck, but I've tried deleting the directory, cloning it again from Github, and reinstalling Jest. Any help would be appreciated!
This is my code.

```
const sumAll = function(min, max) {
    if (!Number.isInteger(min) || !Number.isInteger(max)) return 'ERROR';
    if (min < 0 || max < 0) return 'ERROR';
    if (min > max) [min, max] = [max, min]
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; min <= max; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
};                  
sumAll(1, 4);

// Do not edit below this line
module.exports = sumAll;
```

```
const sumAll = require('./sumAll')

describe('sumAll', () => {
  test('sums numbers within the range', () => {
    expect(sumAll(1, 4)).toEqual(10);
  });
  test('works with large numbers', () => {
    expect(sumAll(1, 4000)).toEqual(8002000);
  });
  test('works with larger number first', () => {
    expect(sumAll(123, 1)).toEqual(7626);
  });
  test('returns ERROR with negative numbers', () => {
    expect(sumAll(-10, 4)).toEqual('ERROR');
  });
  test('returns ERROR with non-number parameters', () => {
    expect(sumAll(10, "90")).toEqual('ERROR');
  });
  test('returns ERROR with non-number parameters', () => {
    expect(sumAll(10, [90, 1])).toEqual('ERROR');
  });
});
```

I expected the test to check in this way. (I took this from another exercise, and all of the other exercises still work except for the 05_sumAll exercise.)
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iva6S.png)

Comment: Your "expected result" is all about leap years? yet your code has nothig to do with dates ... perhaps that's why your code is failing

Comment: The loop won't terminate since `min < max` is always true; you never modified any of them.

Comment: The test ran well again. My problem was in the for loop condition where I used min < max instead of i < max. Thank you very much everyone. <3.